# How long are men allowed to have their hair?

Tags: sunnah

I have heard that the Prophet (PBUH) had his hair from earlobe to shoulder but then some people say men are not allowed long hair it should only be up to their earlobe because women have shoulder length hair.

I want to know how long should a man and woman really have their hair?

Answer (score 7):

`There is authentic evidence that the Prophet (peace be upon him) had long hair.(length of his hair was till his Earlobe)`(according to: http://en.islamtoday.net/node/1126)

Long hair for men is allowed (actually short hair is better for men, although long hair is allowed too but they should take care of their hair).

`Our actions are only by our intention. If someone keeps his hair long to emulate the Prophet (peace be upon him) and take care of it and care about hygiene of them, then it’s ok. On the other hand, if he keeps long hair to emulate the appearance of a certain religious sect or to resemble women, then he is committing a sin that makes him eligible for punishment`(http://en.islamtoday.net/node/1126) according to this hadith:

The Prophet (peace be upon him) said: “Allah curses men who immitate women and women who immitate men.” [Sunan Abî Dâwûd, Sunan Ibn Mâjah, and others]

Women can have long hair, too. Even it 's one of Beauty signs in different cultures.

Finally, someone may grow his/her hair long based on his/her interest. So, with lack of the above stated reasons; it is permissible for him/her to do so, but **it should be in the cultural and usual limitation and they should care about its hygiene.**

For answering I used this links:

- [www.islamweb.net](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=83385)
- [en.islamtoday.net](http://en.islamtoday.net/node/1126)

Comment: If you say the holy prophet was such but we are better to be the other way you better have a good reason supporting your idea, isn't it? Evidently, in those era having such long hairs were common and most do, the holy prophet was sticked to his culture in that sense, so maybe you would like to improve your answer. Shia has its own reason for keeping their hair short, though not obligatory as long as is not imitation of females, it goes back to the very first days after the holy prophet passed a way if I'm not mistaken. Good answer anyway, thanks.

Comment: thanks owari.I said the reason after it:they should take care of it...and care about its hygiene.so,in such days that people work more(but not all of them)it 's hard to often care about their hair(I mean care about its length to not imitate females and special religious group,care about Sort of hair etc)but pay attention I didn't say all of them.however in the past they most have long hair because It was as sunnah,although they didn't have enough time to take care,too;but Today having short hair is ok,too.so,if they can care about,It doesn't matter to have long hair.

Answer (score -4):

Men can have their hair upto earlobe or shoulder. Not longer than that.

Prophet Muhammad's ummah are not allowed to grow their hair more than that.

Comment: @user4638 : Please provide reference